# Hidden OU and hidden users in active directory

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

How to find The Hidden OU and hidden users in business active directory .
i tried to use ***gpresult*** in ***CMD*** but i didnt find what iam looking for please any help

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: If you can't see it, how do you know it's hidden? How do you know it exists?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ADSIEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(WS.10).aspx) to explore and edit any particle of AD, since ADSIEdit is just a LDAP editor. It doesn't *know* anything about the special meanings of the keys and values you can edit there. I maintain several Active Directories (Standard Server and also SBS), and have not seen something like a *hidden* OU / *hidden* user. Someone tries to pull your leg.

**Beware:** Modifying your AD with ADSIEdit can terminally damage it more so than any mistake with RegEdit.

Answer (score 2):

Open "Active Directory Users and Computers", go to "View" (through the Alt key to display the top menu) and choose "Advanced Features".

Answer (score 0):

i was having that issue too. Fortunately, I had it exposed by setting up the filter to show all types of objects.

Go to :
--> Active Directory Users & Computers
--> View tab --> Filter options
--> tick show all types of objects